# JQuery concatenation

Tags: jquery

This works but only if the values are there when the form loads:

```
$('CSZ').val(
$('City').val() + ', ' +  
$('State').val() + ' ' + 
$('Zip']).val()
```

I tried a function like this to try to concatenate as the fields are populated but didn't work.

```
$('CSZ').blur(function() {
$('City').val() + ', ' +  
$('State').val() + ' ' + 
$('ZipCode').val()});
```

But didn't get any results. Any ideas?

Thanks.

```
OK this works. Is there any simpler way to write this?

function SetMainLine() {var csz = 
$(spec['V08_City']).val() + ', ' +  
$(spec['V09_State']).val() + ' ' + 
$(spec['V10_ZipCode']).val();
$(spec['V01_Mainline']).val(csz);
}

spec['V08_City'].onchange = SetMainLine;
spec['V09_State'].onchange = SetMainLine;
spec['V10_ZipCode'].onchange = SetMainLine;

The spec[''] is just calling a form field from a database.
```

Answer (score 3):

The `.blur` function never actually assigns the new value:

```
var val = $('City').val() ...
$(this).val(val);
```

as `meder` points out, you may be missing some selector syntax too.